# Are Body proportions Charts Realistic?

Tags: body-measurements

What do you guys think of this [Ideal Body Proportions Chart](http://www.impulseadventure.com/weights/ideal.html).  It tells me what I have always thought and that is my upper body needs to get bigger.  But it also says that my legs are too big by .75 inches.  I've never been sure if maybe I should work my legs more to increase their size, this chart says no, but a girl just this week told me to not forget to work my lower body, too. Which seems to suggest my lower body may be too straight and slim.

My weight (201 lbs) to height (5'10") ratio is: 2.90

Below are their/my numbers:

- Neck: 17.50/15.50
- Biceps: 16.45/15.372
- Forearm: 13.70/11.625
- Chest: 45.70/43.00
- Waist: 34.25/37.25 - no judging. :-P
- Hips: 41.10/41.625
- Thigh: 24.65/24.75
- Calf: 16.45/16.50

One measurement that is missing is shoulders which depends on your deltoids which can't be measured individually.  Also, how do you measure traps? Or would the extra weight of the trap muscles force to increase of the other muscle proportions in the chart.

Lastly, who actually takes this chart seriously.  I've seen it displayed in a few sites.

**Update:**
Ok, did some research and found [this for shoulders](http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Calculate-Your-Ideal-Shoulder-Size---It-All-Starts-With-Your-Height&id=2713952). And this seems to point to the [Golden Ratio of 1.618](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

**THE QUESTION:  Is it realistic to follow the above body proportions chart?  Or should I use my own judgement?**

Comment: So what's the question in here?

Comment: "What do you guys think of this Ideal Body Proportions Chart?"  Is it realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, nobody takes these body charts seriously.
They are intended for bodybuilders in contest shape, so they do not apply to many people.

Without a visual, it's hard to say for sure, but I bet you tend to carry more weight in your lower body.  I say this mostly because of the measurements for your waist and calves.  That being said, I think your thighs are not too big, but too fat.  These measurements are only good comparisons if you're very lean.

Also, most people don't carry much fat in their forearms.  Your forearms are significantly smaller than this charts ideal, even more than your biceps.  That indicates that you carry much less muscle than what this chart references.

Shoulder development is limited by your trap strength, and your trap size is reflected in the neck measurement.  According to the old military height and weight requirements, if you were over the suggested weight for your class, they would measure your neck.  If the neck measurement was big enough, it indicated that you carried more muscle mass than the average man, and so your additional weight could be waived.

I don't think you should strive to have the same measurements as this chart, but the same proportions as the chart.  You should be the same percentage smaller then each measurement.

Comment: Actually just my gut is fat, but I can still see the six pack, my legs and calves are fairly lean.  My lower body is more muscular than my upper body.  The reason I'm asking these questions is because every mirror I look into seems top be distorted a bit, so not really sure what I look like.  Even the mirrors at the gym are angled downwards.

Comment: A picture would allow me to answer your question thoroughly.

Comment: Also, your actual height and weight would be more helpful than your weight to height ratio.

Comment: Just added it: 201 lbs, 5'10"

Comment: And all my test give me: ~20% fat.

Comment: Considering your height, weight, and bodyfat, your bodyfat is too high to compare yourself to a proportion chart.  As I said, it is intended to be a reference for someone who is very lean.  When I say lean, I'm talking about 8% or below for men.  Although you said that your legs are lean, I beg to differ.  Some people store fat interstitially (within the muscle) and can have separation between muscles that makes them look leaner than they actually are.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are so worried about your proportions when you are quite fat. I wouldn't discuss proportional aesthetics until you are at least < 13% - preferably 10.